# Open MicroStrategy report without showing login page with C# code

Tags: c#, authentication, microstrategy

I have below MicroStrategy report. When you open it, it ask for username and password. How can I give username and password in C# code to open this report automatically without showing this login page?
http://13.73.207.20/microstrategy/asp/Main.aspx?Server=MICROSTRATEGY2&Project=TTG&Port=0&evt=2048001&src=Main.aspx.2048001&visMode=0&currentViewMedia=1&&documentID=0F113C664A246262A8A66C9C5F31F933&hiddenSections=path

Answer (score 0):

You could feed by default the username and password values and add a EventListener to the page.

DOMContentLoaded https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded, to execute the submit

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of pages that will help

1) Creating a session
https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/_CurrentGARelease/docs/projects/WebSDK/Content/topics/objbeans/Session_Creation_in_a_NET_Environment.htm

and

2) logging in with sessionID URL parameter
https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/_CurrentGARelease/docs/projects/WebSDK/Content/topics/objbeans/Session_Creation_in_a_NET_Environment.htm

Obviously with the URL API, you should never use the &uid and &pwd parameters, because that's plain text.

Get a sessionID from the intelligence server, and use that sessionID parameter (&usrSmgr) in the URL